# Execute python executable and script inlucing full path

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Im trying to create a python script with executes a series of python and sql scripts.

Some need to be executed using one python executable and some using another.

I've tried

```
from subprocess import call 
call([r"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\pythonw.exe", r"C:\Path\to\python\file\blabla.py"])
```

And

```
call([r"cd C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3", "pythonw.exe", r"C:\Path\to\python\file\blabla.py"])
```

But the script isnt being executed.

I think the problem might be "How to execute an .exe file in windows terminal including full path to it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my code. It is working well in my side.

```
from subprocess import call

call([r"C:\Python38\python.exe", r"E:\python\hello.py"])
```

As i think, the problem is that you use pythonw.exe.
if you use pythonw.exe, you can see any log in terminal.
Pythonw is useful for running script with GUI.